# Angular - Can I have custom HTML Structure whenever I create a component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-schematics

Currently, I am working on an Angular project where I have so many pages having similar HTML structure.

I have a fixed HTML Structure and what all I need is, whenever I create a 
component, component.html file should contain my fixed HTML structure by default.

How can I do that, Is that something possible?

If it is, Please help!

Comment: Just to confirm I got this right, what you want to achieve is replace the default content for the view file generated by "ng generate component"?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist

Comment: @SPArchaeologist - We are building a design language system of our own and all components have almost same HTML structure, So we thought of having a template which have fixed headers, footers and consistent spacing between the elements across the site. So, whenever we generate a component, It should generate HTML file having our basic structure.

Comment: Try having a look at Angular Schematics. It'll provide you with a way of extending AngularCLI's pre-defined Schematics to create your own and do the needful there. Here's a great article about it:

https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2

Comment: Please take a look at ng-include https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp